# Azure / SharePoint Server Farm Failing

Tags: sharepoint, azure

I am attempting to create a SharePoint Server Farm using the option via the New menu in Azure. I've tried like 5 times now and each time, it fails after about an hour.

The error is so cryptic that I cannot figure out exactly what is going on.

The operation name is: Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/extensions/write
The status is: Failed

And then another,

The operation name is: Update deployment
The status is: Failed.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do any VMs get provisioned at all?  If so does it always fail at the same point in the process? Did you check your Azure Operations Logs (Old Portal > Managament Services > Operations Logs)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience using the "new" preview portal when deploying Databases. This portal uses Resource Manager to deploy it's resources which is a new way of doing things. Anyhow, I used the PowerShell command:

Get-AzureResourceGroupLog -Name ResourceGroupName

This provided me the detail to understand what was happening with the deployment. I had to adjust my Datacenter because the one I was trying to use was hot.

I talk a little more about the other options this command has here:
http://devian.co/?p=1181

Comment: What is the Resource Manager (1.0) equivalent for this?